# Could not resolve placeholder for some property

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dbDataSource' defined in
>   cz.ita.javaee.config.DatabaseConfiguration: Unexpected exception
>   during bean creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'db.jndi' in value "${db.jndi}"   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1739)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'db.jndi' in value "${db.jndi}"   at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:809)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:715)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>     ... 55 more

My Database Configuration class:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "dbDataSource")
    @Profile("!development")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${db.jndi}") String dbJndiName) {
        JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return lookup.getDataSource(dbJndiName);
    }

    @Profile("development")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${development.db.driver}") String dbDriver,
            @Value("${development.db.url}") String dbUrl,
            @Value("${development.db.username}") String dbUsername,
            @Value("${development.db.password}") String dbPassword) {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(dbUrl);
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriver);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

}
```

And AppConfig:

```
@Import({DatabaseConfiguration.class, MailSenderConfiguration.class})
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

}

Hi, I got error above and I don't know how to fix it, can you help me? My project working fine until I've added this bean:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:mail.properties")
public class MailSenderConfiguration {

@Value("${mail.smtp.host}")
private String mailHost;

@Value("${mail.smtp.port}")
private int mailPort;

@Value("${mail.username}")
private String mailUsername;

@Value("${mail.password}")
private String mailPassword;

@Value("${mail.protocol}")
private String mailProtocol;

@Value("${mail.smtp.auth}")
private boolean mailAuth;

@Value("${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}")
private String mailEnableTls;

@Value("${mail.smtp.debug}")
private boolean mailDebug;

@Bean
public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

    mailSender.setHost(mailHost);
    mailSender.setPort(mailPort);
    mailSender.setUsername(mailUsername);
    mailSender.setPassword(mailPassword);

    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", mailProtocol);
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", mailAuth);
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", mailEnableTls);
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.debug", mailDebug);
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);

    return mailSender;
}

@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("mail.properties"));
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your property source config in MailSenderConfiguration is overriding the one in AppConfig.

You can remove PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean from MailSenderConfiguration, and in AppConfig, set additional location for "mail.properties" (use setLocations() method instead of setLocation()):

```
@Import({DatabaseConfiguration.class, MailSenderConfiguration.class})
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"), new ClassPathResource("mail.properties"));
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean is loaded before trying to evaluate properties by making the bean static. Spring instantiates static beans before other beans definitions.

```
@Import({DatabaseConfiguration.class, MailSenderConfiguration.class})
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for other suggestions maybe it works for them but in my case it's like : some time it's happened due to JDK mismatch so, better first check your IDE JDK version and project JDK version.